# Restoring SQL Database with NoRecovery stuck

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

We are moving from a SQL 2008 standalone instance to a SQL 2016 HA Failover Cluster Instance (FCI) with an AlwaysOn Basic Availability Group (BAG) configured to replicate to a standalone DR instance off site.

I am trying to restore the database from a .bak file on the FCI however after it finishes successfully the database is stuck in a DatabaseName(Restoring...) state.

If i restore with recovery it works fine however when i then go to set up the BAG it fails as it needed to be restored with NoRecovery option.

Could anyone shed some light on what may be the issue here? Does the backup of the database need to be done a particular way? Could it be that the original database is set in a simple recovery mode?